# Having context menu for NSButton created dynamically

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

I am creating NSButton dynamically in the cocoa application which is fine. However once the application launches, I want to perform right click on the NSButton created or would like to have context menu for the NSBUtton. How to achieve this?

Comment: Why would the user right-click on a button? Is it a borderless button showing an image? Otherwise, I can't imagine why anyone would expect it to have a contextual menu.

Comment: The contextual menu is required to call some IBACtion's.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Why would *the user* right-click on a button? How would they know that right-clicking *on a button* will produce a menu?

Comment: Because thats the way the user wants it.

Comment: Is there any updates on this from somebody???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass NSButton and override mousedown or menu for event